# How to use OpenVPN server to connect to the AKS Private Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, openvpn

I have a private `Azure` AKS Kubernetes cluster. And I need to connect to it. So I have few options, out of them I would like to try the following 2

1. Have a bastion server where I can login there and execute `kubectl` commands - But in this case I have to log into the bastion server
2. Setup an `openvpn` server in the above bastion and use openvpn client to connect to it and execute `kubectl` commands from my local machine

In the Step 2, everything works fine (openvpn server, connection to it etc), except that I cannot execute `kubectl` commands.

After connected to the openvpn server, From my local machine, I tried resolving the API server endpoint of the AKS cluster like below and it resolves without any issue:

```
// in my local machine, connected to the openvpn
nslookup <RETRACTED>.<RETRACTED>.privatelink.germanywestcentral.azmk8s.io

Server:     <RETRACTED>
Address:    <RETRACTED>#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <RETRACTED>.<RETRACTED>.privatelink.germanywestcentral.azmk8s.io
Address: 10.1.4.4
```

It is the same result I get when I tried after logging in to the jumphost.

But only difference I found was that, since this API server endpoint `<RETRACTED>.<RETRACTED>.privatelink.germanywestcentral.azmk8s.io` is some kind of a load balancer endppoint, I tried to `telnet` to port `443`

```
// within the jumphost

telnet <RETRACTED>.<RETRACTED>.privatelink.germanywestcentral.azmk8s.io 443

Trying 10.1.4.4...
Connected to <RETRACTED>.<RETRACTED>.privatelink.germanywestcentral.azmk8s.io.
Escape character is '^]'.


// after connecting to VPN and tried the same in local machine
telnet <RETRACTED>.<RETRACTED>.privatelink.germanywestcentral.azmk8s.io 443

Trying 10.1.4.4...
```

But it doesn't connect. I believe this is something I need to fix from the VPN side?
If so, how can I fix this? Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am using openvpn access server with saml to communicate to private aks cluster. My openvpn access server version is 2.11.1
By default this option is enabled in openvpn admin login page: "Do not alter clients' DNS server settings". (openvpn admin page --> vpn settings --> DNS settings).
You need to enable this option: "Have clients use the same DNS servers as the Access Server host".
Since openvpn is deployed in the same vnet as aks cluster, it will use the same dns servers.
After enabling that option, download your .ovpn file again.
Connect to openvpn and now you can do kubectl commands from your localmachine

[image: openvpn-image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your inputs. This setting is already enabled by default and I still have the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Previously I tried with openvpn 2.4.7 version, I got the same issue as above.
Use with openvpn3: `openvpn3 session-start --config test.ovpn`
I tried with both normal user and saml user. It's working fine for me.
I was able to reach k8s from my local machine.

Comment: HI, I a, using the latest version of the openvpn server, Latest downloaded from the page. `wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add - /
echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian focal main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list / 
sudo apt update \
sudo apt install openvpn-as -y `

Comment: You need to use openvpn3.https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/openvpn-3-client-for-linux/ . With openvpn3 I'm not facing any issues

Comment: Hi, thank you, could I get the commands to install, and connect to the openvpn server

Comment: 1. sudo wget https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub
2. sudo apt-key add openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub
3. sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-focal.list
4. sudo apt update
5. sudo apt install openvpn3

Connecting through openvon3:
1. openvpn3 session-start --config <give ur ovpn file here>

Comment: You can check this link for downloading openvpn3
https://openvpn.net/cloud-docs/openvpn-3-client-for-linux/

Comment: Hi, but this is for installing the client version. I need the commands to install `openvpn` server and generate config file.

Comment: You can get the config file (ovpn file) by creating users in openvpn. 
Check this link: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/microsoft-azure-byol-appliance-quick-start-guide/